# Sprite Kit Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to build a scrolling table of game center scores in an SKScene. Is there a way to use sprite kit and storyboards/xibs? `[self addChild:customTable]` on an SKScene doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIKit elements like `UITableView`, `UIView`, etc cannot be used as children of SpriteKit nodes. You can place a `UITableView` on top of a `SKView`/`UIView` but that comes out as crude. I would suggest you use a normal `UIViewController` to display your Game Center scores.

However, if you still need to display the scores using SpriteKit, there is a component called ScrollNode which might do the trick. You can find it [here](https://github.com/lboban/ScrollNode).

Comment: That link gets a 404, btw.

Comment: @user1639164 the component never worked properly, so the author must have deleted it.