# Why is Sprite Kit Text Resolution Slightly Pixelated?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I was thinking of putting adding a UITableView to a SKView, but I read the answer here which mentioned it would be 'crude':
[Sprite Kit Table View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339818/sprite-kit-table-view)

I tested it, and the text in the tableview is slightly pixelated.  Out of curiousity, I also made a simple stand-alone SKLabelNode and noticed it was not retina-quality either.

My question(s) is why is the text in these cases not retina?  Is there a way I can make them sharper as if they were rendered by UIKit?  What is the underlying concept I need to understand with respect to text and Sprite Kit?

Comment: what font (name)? what font size? is the node scaled? The only thing I observed is that you can't go lower than a specific fontSize, ie 10px or so. The reason may be that fonts are rasterized (ie drawn to a texture) rather than drawn as vector graphics like I assume UIKit does.

Comment: I am using HelveticaNeue-Light at fontSize = 30.  Using UIKit it is very sharp.  The scene is init with size set as follows in the ViewController (a stock approach I believe): SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

Comment: hmmm maybe changing scene scaleMode affects this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My simulator was set to test using the iPad, not iPad retina. D'oh